# Javascript: Create temp file on the client without dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data from files by input labels and I encrypt the data.
Then I want to post the encrypted data (Blob format) to the server (PHP) by Ajax (jQuery).
I have tried to use `readAsBinaryString` and `btoa` functions to get base64-format-string and post the string.

The solution works well on small files. When I try to process large file (over 100M), the page shuts down.
So I want to write the encrypted data into a temp file on the client and upload the file to the server. But I find some ways about creating files all need a dialog to place files.
How to create temp file on the client without dialog? Or is there anyway else to post large data to the server?

Comment: So what have you tried that require dialog? What about indexedDB?

Comment: Are you trying to encode the whole file at once?

Comment: @ A. Wolff I need to post the encryped data to the server rather than store the data locally.The 'require-dialog' way will make the process more complex ("select a file to encrypt; find a directory to place the encryped data;select and post the encryped file").

Comment: @JimmyB Yes, I read the blob_package and encode the result at once. But I can get the encode result on the chrome-devtools (slowly), and the page shut down when I try to post the data out (maybe when ajax processData).